# Ruby array group_by nested hash sum fields

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.3

I have array data from Siz.requirements.all (model)
model fields (siz,heigth,wigth,kol)

```
[{:siz=>10, :heigth = 30, :wigth = 20, :kol = 24},
 {:siz=>10, :heigth = 30, :wigth = 10, :kol = 24},
 {:siz=>10, :heigth = 30, :wigth = 20, :kol = 33},
 {:siz=>10, :heigth = 20, :wigth = 20, :kol = 3},
 {:siz=>10, :heigth = 20, :wigth = 20, :kol = 5},...
```

how create array or hash with group by fields
for example:

```
[{:siz=>10 => {:heigth=>"30" => {:wigth=>"20" => {:sum_kol => sum(kol)}}},         
{:siz=>10 => {:heigth=>"30" => {:wigth=>"10" => {:sum_kol => sum(kol)}}},
{:siz=>10 => {:heigth=>"20" => {:wigth=>"20" => {:sum_kol => sum(kol)}}}]
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Are you able to provide a better example of what your inputs and expected outputs are?

Comment: are :siz, :heigth, :wigth, and :kol supposed to be :size, :height, :width, and :col? 

I don't understand your nesting structure; you aren't actually combining all the elements with the same size into one element, so the nesting seems somewhat pointless.  Seems like it would make more  sense to have something like  `{ 10 => { 20 => { 20 => sum }, 30 => { 10 => sum, 20 => sum } } }`

Comment: @MarkReed Yes like this  `  { 10 => { 20 => { 20 => sum }, 30 => { 10 => sum, 20 => sum } } } `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is coming from a database, I would look at using the database to do the grouping and summarizing for you.  But here's one way to do it in Ruby:

```
raw_data = [ {:siz=>10, :heigth => 30, :wigth =>20, :kol =>24},
             {:siz=>10, :heigth =>30, :wigth =>10, :kol =>24},
             {:siz=>10, :heigth =>30, :wigth =>20, :kol =>33},
             {:siz=>10, :heigth =>20, :wigth =>20, :kol =>3},
             {:siz=>10, :heigth =>20, :wigth =>20, :kol =>5} ]

# create a hash that defaults to three levels of nested hash values,
# with 0s at the leaves
summary = Hash.new do Hash.new do Hash.new do 0 end end end    

# populate it
raw_data.each do |rec|
  size, height, width, col = rec.values_at(:siz,:heigth,:wigth,:kol)
  summary[size][height][width] += col
end

summary # => {10=>{30=>{20=>57, 10=>24}, 20=>{20=>8}}}
```

Normally it would more idiomatic in Ruby to use `inject`/`reduce` instead of the initialization + update loop:

```
summary = raw_data.reduce(Hash.new do Hash.new do Hash.new do 0 end end end)
 do |summary,rec|
   size, height, width, col = rec.values_at(:siz,:heigth,:wigth,:kol)
   summary[size][height][width] += col
   summary
end
```

But with the default-laden hash and the need to return the hash at the end of the reduce block, I think the original version is cleaner here.

Comment: Very nicely @MarkReed. But values_at not method error. I am refactor this line. Thery thanks.

Comment: ? values_at is definitely a valid method on Hashes in ruby 1.8+.  If you're having trouble we can fire up a chat session.